# How to compare two TStringLists?

Tags: delphi

I am currently trying to compare two `TStringList` and whether one containts items of another.

As an example.

```
sl1 := TStringList.Create;
for i := 0 to record.count - 1 do
  sl.add(record[i]);
```

This gets executed on the start of the program and is not updated until the program starts again. Note that the `record` is a string and can be more than one word. (e.g. jack, thomas lember, lester,...)

Then I have a timer which looks like this.

```
sl2 := TStringList.Create;
for i := 0 to record.count - 1 do
  sl2.add(record[i]);

if sl1 item is not in sl2 then  <-- stuck here            
  s := s + record[i];
```

I want to compare both lists and then create a string of what is missing. This should be easy, but the position of strings can change. What is in `sl1[2]` can now be in `sl2[7]`. To the `s` string I want to add only items that are missing and didn't change the position.

Comment: Is string order in the lists important? Could you apply sorting?

Comment: Sounds like a set or a dictionary are actually the collections that you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare each item of the sl1 with each item of the sl2.

```
for i := 0 to sl1.count - 1 do
begin

   found := false;

   for j := 0 to sl2.count - 1 do
   begin
      if sl1[i] = sl2[j] then
      begin
         found := true;
         break;
      end;

   end;

   if not Found then
      slMissing.add(sl1[i])


end;
```

You can use `TStringList.IndexOf` instead of the inner loop if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to clarify to anyone looking at this in the future, you cannot use length(sl2) and must use .count. not sure why

Comment: Was just an example. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:

> `if sl1 item is not in sl2 then`  <-- stuck here

You can use sl2.IndexOf() like this:

```
if sl2.IndexOf(sl1[i]) < 0 then
```

But if both lists are and remain sorted, you can probably skip a few items, as the index in one list can never be lower than that in the other.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While I have not used IndexOf before, after reading for the whole 30 seconds, that my brain can function, am I wrong to assume that this will not work if the second list is either longer or shorter than the one I am comparing?

Comment: IndexOf will always work, even if the list is empty. If it can't find the item, it will return -1. The **probably** faster way requires some thinking, which I haven't done yet, so I didn't give a ready solution for that. The IndexOf loop should work anyway.

Comment: If both list can have different length, then I suppose it would be faster to always loop thru the shortest list and do IndexOf on the longer list ?

Comment: @GuidoG: since IndexOf does a sequential search through the list, the difference won't be noticeable, I guess.

Comment: well I don know. If the first list has 2 items, and the second has 100 items, will it then be faster to do 2 times IndexOf on a list of 100, or 100 times on a list of 2 ?

Comment: When I think about it, in the worst case both approaches will search exact the same amount of times. So I guess it really does not makes a difference

Comment: It doesn't matter a lot if you do 2 x 100 or 100 x 2 the same comparison.

Comment: I've never really understood this `< 0` test since `= -1` seems much clearer and more explicit. Using `< 0` leaves the reader wondering about whether negative values other than `-1` can occur.

Comment: IndexOf returns either -1 when nothing found, or the found index. So yes a check on `= -1` is more clear and exact then a check on `< 0` I have to agree here. In most cases one wants to know if it succeeded so `>= 0` is what I find most in code here

Comment: @David: I don't quite understand what you don't understand about a `< 0` test. Quite straightforward, IMO. FWIW, a test against 0 is usually slightly more optimized than a test against -1 or any other non-zero value. I assume the optimizer will turn one into another anyway, but I prefer to test against 0. And it may be -1 for a string list, but it may just as well be any value < 0 in other situations (a subtraction is pretty fast, so it is often used for such compariosons), so I simply do the <0 test.

Comment: @GuidoG: Note that `>= 0` is the opposite of `< 0`. I don't understand what is wrong with a `< 0` test, especially since tests against zero (**any test**, e.g. <0, =0 and >0 or any combination) are usually slightly simpler than tests against any non-zero value.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that test and it will work. Its just that this function returns -1 in case of nothing found, so why not check on `-1` in stead on `< 0` That is all David is saying I think

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's not about speed. It's about readability. And even if it were about speed, there's no performance difference here. To my way of logic, -1 is a sentinel. Its value is the important aspect, not that it is negative, and valid indices are not.

Comment: I think that < 0 is very readable especially since 0 and anything above is a possible valid index, **so anything that is *not* >= 0 is invalid**, no matter if it is -1 or -754 or -MaxInt. Comparing against a **magic number** like -1 (which applies in some cases and not in other) is IMO **less** readable. Unless you give it a name like `const InvalidStringsIndex = -1` and you can be sure that you always get a -1 and not just anything invalid. Its actual value is not the important aspect, just that it is **not valid**. But let's agree to disagree.

Comment: In other words, I think it is easier to remember that any negative index is invalid than that it must be a specific value, unless someone gave a meaningful name to that value and it is used throughout all source code. -1 may be a sentinel value, but it easier to remember *anything negative* than *magic number -1*, IMO.

Comment: FWIW, yes there is a slight performance difference. Flags are automatically set for 0, so not always an explicit test is needed. But a comparison against an explicit nonzero value does require such a test. Won't make a big difference, but there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop thru both stringlists and compare each with each until you found a match

```
sl1.Add('one');
sl1.Add('two');

sl2.Add('two');
sl2.Add('one');


i := 0;
j := 0;
found := FALSE;

while (i < sl1.Count) and not found do
begin
  j := 0;
  while (j < sl2.Count) and not found do
  begin
    found := sl1[i] = sl2[j];
    inc(j);
  end;
  inc(i);
end;

if found then
  ShowMessage('found: item ' + IntToStr(i) + ' was on ' + IntToStr(j) + ' in the second list')
else
  ShowMessage('Not found');
```

Alternative solution

```
i := 0;
found := FALSE;

while (i < sl1.Count) and not found do
begin
  j := sl2.IndexOf(sl1[i]);
  Found := j >= 0;

  inc(i);
end;
```

Comment: @echkart There was a bug in my code, I fixed it. Just above the second loop you need to initialize the variable `j`

Comment: I also added an alternative solution, which is based on  the the answer of @RudyVelthuis . I suggest you try which one is the fastest and use that